# Uglify is throwing an error that I do not understand

Tags: javascript, gulp

I did an npm and jspm update and now when I try to run my gulp minify on my javascript, I get this error.

[image]

I'm not sure what the error means.  The site.min.js is what it will generate so I'm not sure how the error is there.  Any help to point me in the right direction would be great.  My gulp

Comment: Is it angular code or are you injecting any services / factories ?

Comment: Please post the content of the site.min.js

Comment: It's not angular.  I am using Aurelia but I exempt those paths from the min process

Comment: Not sure if I can.  It belongs to my company.  I don't understand the error.

Comment: try compiling it with closure compile to find errors in the javascript @ https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Comment: Could it be something as simple as a missing comma or semi-colon?

Comment: When I put it in the closure compile, it was successful

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling your sources with closure compile @ https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Comment: compile the min file?

Comment: I just put the min file in there and the compilation was a success

Comment: We can't say anything without seeing the code. So copy only simplified code throwing the error.